# Conjoiners vs conjunctions vs articles

Tags: articles, conjunctions

I've heard that [conjoiners](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conjoiner) (in terms of grammar) are similar to [articles](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/articles?s=t).

According to sources, **articles** can be words such as *the*, *an*, *a*, *some* (in unique cases). **Conjunctions** can be *and*, *but*, *as well as*. Are **conjoiners** the same as conjunctions? Or are they closer to articles instead?

My question is: Is there a clear difference between each, or can the terms be used interchangeably with one or the other (articles or conjunctions)?

> You're missing an article in this sentence.

And:

> You're missing a conjoiner in this sentence.

Or:

> You're missing an conjunction in this sentence.

And:

> You're missing a conjoiner in this sentence.

Or is the term *conjoiner* archaic and no longer is used, unless for very unique cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "conjoiner" is sometimes used in linguistic theory, but rarely in terms of English grammar.

A **conjunction** in English refers to a specific set of words; "and," "or," "but," "although." A conjunction is a **part of speech,** like a noun or a verb.

A **conjoiner** is a linguistics concept that refers to any linguistic construct that plays the same role. In some languages, the role of some conjunctions (especially subordinating conjunctions) are played by units other than independent words, such as verb endings.

Neither has anything to do with articles, which are separate parts of speech.

If your sentence was:

> *The river ran down to sea

you would say:

> You're missing an **article** in that sentence.

If your sentence was:

> *The river wound its way down the mountain through the forest

you would say:

> You're missing a **conjunction** in that sentence.

You would never tell someone they were missing a **conjoiner,** unless you were a theoretical linguist talking to another theoretical linguist.

Comment: [Conjoiners](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conjoiner): (Grammar) to join as coordinate elements, especially as coordinate clauses. Aren't clauses that have a coordinate relationship (i.e. when it has the same information without any dependence to the other clause) used to create sentences formed by using conjunctions or articles between their particular clauses?

Comment: That's not a definition of "conjoiner." It's from the Dictionary.com page for "conjoiner," but if you look carefully, you'll see that it's actually the definition of "conjoin." "Conjoiner" is simply one possible noun form of "conjoin."

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard the word *conjoiner* in a grammatical context, and would take it as a synonym of *conjunction*.

Syntactically, conjunctions and articles are utterly different.

Comment: Hi Colin, I came across this quite some time ago when we were discussing Shakespearean theater and how he would structure his sentences in certain way. It's been so long that I've forgotten how it is applicable, but the term has stuck with me all these years. Sadly, I cannot find anything that actually helps clarify my doubt (why I ended up posting a question). I'm starting to think that both articles *and* conjunctions are forms of conjoiners and the more I look into it the more I'm convinced that there is a much more complex answer to this. Perhaps I should ask *what* a conjoiner is?

Comment: As I said, I've never encountered _conjoiner_ in linguistics (though @chapka says they have) and don't know what somebody might use it to mean. But I would expect it to have some meaning to do with conjoining separate things, and I can't see any way that articles might be so described.